# OnTimedEvent additional Argument

Tags: vb.net, timer-jobs

I am trying to build some scheduler using ontimedevent.

To keep it fast, I want to fill an array before starting the Timer and then pass it on to my

```
"Private Shared Sub OnTimedEvent(source As Object, e As ElapsedEventArgs)"
```

Is it possible to add the array as argument to the addhandler, i.e.

`AddHandler aTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf OnTimedEvent(array)`

(Unfortunately this does not work)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not create the array as member variable - so you can access it within your class?

Comment: I am quite a newbie. Could you please help me how to do this.

Comment: You don't know what is the member variable of class? http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ke6sh835.aspx